# Propagating NSError from inside an NSOperation's autoreleasepool

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsoperation

### What I currently have

I'm having some trouble propagating my `NSErrors` that are created inside an `NSOperation`'s `main` method.

```
@interface FooOperation()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSError * error;

@end

@implementation FooOperation

- (id) initWithError:(NSError * __autoreleasing *) error
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _error = * error;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) main
{
    NSError * innerError = nil;
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Call some methods, such as:
        [self someMethodWithError:&innerError];
        if (innerError) {    // many of them can throw errors
            _error = innerError;    // _error is set just fine here
            return;
        }
        // call some other methods...
    }
}

@end
```

And I would try to use this operation and get the error like this:

```
NSOperationQueue * opQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSError * error = nil;
FooOperation * operation = [[FooOperation alloc] initWithError:&error];
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    if (error) {
    // never happens, error is always nil here!
    }
}];


[opQueue addOperation:operation];
```

### What I want to do

After most of these `errors` I will make an `UIAlertView` to show what the problem was and a possible recovery solution. I know from inside my `NSOperation` I can make a call to the main queue and just show the alert from there, but I wanted something like this to be called from my `ViewController` to keep UI code in one place.

*edit : I guess what I'm trying to do would be similar to how in Java or C# you would throw an exception from the operation, and catch it in the view controller to show my error message there*

Comment: That doesn't look as if it should compile. And there's some major misunderstanding going on about the difference between NSError* and NSError**.

Comment: @gnasher729 I had a typo on my init method. But your comment could have been more helpful if you would point that out instead of just saying it doesn't compile.